# Android: Display menu as List

Tags: android, navigation

In my app, I want to display a menu as a List. I already have an existing menu XML file, which I am using for the bottom navigation, but I put a few menu items into a separate menu XML, which I now want to display in a List.

But so far I have only found ways of displaying menus as a context menu, in a drawer or as a navigation menu. Is it possible to use the menu XML in a List or do I have to resort to a standard ListView? Here is a mockup of how it should look:

[image: Navigation tab]

This is the menu XML for it (right now only has the first two items):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_illness"
          android:title="@string/illness"
          android:icon="@drawable/medical" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_vacation"
          android:title="@string/vacation"
          android:icon="@drawable/tree" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a full-screen dialog fragment? You'd need a normal xml layout (I'm not sure if works with a menu layout) and you could inflate it upon pressing a button/icon.

In my app, I've got an options menu and I display a dialog fragment upon touching an icon. Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionbar_button_config:
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            YourDialogFragment yourDialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
            yourDialogFragment.show(fm, "dialog_fragment");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, 0); // here you can define a full-screen style
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_config_fragment, null);

    builder.setView(content)
            .setTitle("Sensor Config")
            .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    SensorConfigFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

This creates a dialog fragment with title, "Done" and "Cancel" buttons, but you don't have to have those. If you don't need those, you can use OnCreateView instead of onCreateDialog and inflate your layout there.

Comment: What is the advantage here over using an actual activity? The whole reason for my question is that I want to be able to use the menu XML, if I don't then there are many possible solutions.

Comment: I think you can only use a menu as an options/context/popup menu. As far as I understand your question, you want a menu that is full-screen and looks like a list, as on the screenshot, right? You could do something like that with a full-screen dialog fragment, that is the advantage. Of course there might be better solutions.